# How do I get this to function properly? It is giving me the wrong day on Easter weekend

Tags: sas

So, I want to find the fifth working day before a given day, and that means not including weekends and bank holidays. On a normal week it seems to work fine, but if I try start date of 07APR2015, which is a tuesday after Easter friday, weekend and Easter monday, it returns the wrong fifth day.

The txt file contains:

```
bhol
01jan2015
03apr2015
06apr2015
04may2015
25may2015
31aug2015
25dec2015
28dec2015
```

The code is as follows:

```
options mprint mlogic symbolgen;

proc import out=bhols datafile="C:\Users\me\Documents\bhols.txt" dbms=csv replace;
label;
run;

data bholdates;
  set bhols;
  sasdate=input(bhol,date9.);
  today=input("07apr2015",date9.);
  weekday=weekday(today);
  call symputx("todayd",today,"g");
run;

proc sql ;
  select sasdate into :bhols separated by " "
  from bholdates;
quit;

%macro five;
data test;
/*  format today day day5 date9.;*/
  retain count;
  count=0;
  today=&todayd;
  day=&todayd-1;
  do until(count=1);
  weekday=weekday(day);
  if day in(&bhols) or weekday in(1,7) then do;
  day=day-1;
  end;
  if day not in(&bhols) and weekday not in(1,7) then do;
    count=count+1;
    weekday5=weekday(day);
    day5=day;
    day=day-1;
  end;
  end;
run;
%mend;
%five;
```

I want the variable day5 to contain the fifth working day before the given date.

Comment: Would you consider creating your own custom interval instead? If you have the holidays in a file and SAS 9.3+ this is a good option, then you can use intck/intnx function.

Answer (score 1):

I would try something like this:

```
/* Step back 5 days */
do i = 1 to 5;
  day - 1;
  /* Step back an extra day for each weekend or bank holiday encountered */
  do while(weekday(day) in (1, 7) or day in (&bhols.));
    day - 1;
  end;
end;
```

The `do i = 1 to 5` will step back through the workdays, and the `do while()` will ensure that you step over all weekends and bank holidays even when they are adjacent.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way (and I do this a fair amount) is to just find all the dates that are not weekends and holidays.  Look-up the value 5 before your value.

```
/*All weekdays in the year*/
data not_hols;
format date date9.;
do date="01JAN2015"d to "31DEC2015"d;
    if weekday(date) not in (6,7) then
        output;
end;
run;

/*Delete the holidays*/
proc sql noprint;
delete from not_hols
where date in (select bhols from bhols);
quit;

/*Add an index*/
data not_hols;
set not_hols;
index = _n_;
run;

/*Date to find*/
%let find_dt=07apr2015;

/*Look up the date based on the index being -5 from the value of
  find_dt */
proc sql noprint;
select date format date9.
    into :back5
from not_hols
where index = (
    select index-5 
    from not_hols 
    where date = "&find_dt"d
);
quit;

%put Back 5 from &find_dt = &back5;
```

The first part of creating the `NOT_HOLS` data can be done once and saved in a permanent location. Then you can just use the SQL to get the date you need, when you need it.